# Java code for guessing game not printing anything

Tags: java

So I have a Computer Science course at school in which we learn Java. We were assigned to do a simple text based recreation of the guessing game. I got it done until this point, and I cannot seem to find where I messed up because there is nothing printed when I run the core.

This is the code:

```
    public class GuessGame 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  { 
    new GuessGame();
  }  
  public GuessGame () 
  { 
    char end = 'y';
    while (end!='y')
    {
      System.out.println ("Welcome to the Guessing Game!");
      System.out.println ("\nThe computer has picked a number");
      System.out.println ("between 1 and 100. Try to guess it.");
      int num = (int)(Math.random()*(100-1)+1);
      int guess = IBIO.inputInt ("Guess the number: ");
      if (guess==num)
        System.out.println ("You got it!");
      else if (guess>num)
        System.out.println ("That is too high.");
      else
        System.out.println ("That is too low.");
      end = IBIO.inputChar ("Exit game? (y/n)");
    }
  }
}
```

By the way, IBIO is a class provided by my IB program that we use to make Input/Output statements.

This is IBIO.java:

```
    public class IBIO
{
    static void output (String info)
    {
 System.out.println (info);
    }


    static void output (char info)
    {
 System.out.println (info);
    }


    static void output (byte info)
    {
 System.out.println (info);
    }


    static void output (int info)
    {
 System.out.println (info);
    }


    static void output (long info)
    {
 System.out.println (info);
    }


    static void output (double info)
    {
 System.out.println (info);
    }


    static void output (boolean info)
    {
 System.out.println (info);
    }


    static String input (String prompt)
    {
 String inputLine = "";
 System.out.print (prompt);
 try
 {
     inputLine = (new java.io.BufferedReader (new java.io.InputStreamReader (System.in))).readLine ();
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     String err = e.toString ();
     System.out.println (err);
     inputLine = "";
 }
 return inputLine;
    }


    static String inputString (String prompt)
    {
 return input (prompt);
    }


    static String input ()
    {
 return input ("");
    }


    static int inputInt ()
    {
 return inputInt ("");
    }


    static double inputDouble ()
    {
 return inputDouble ("");
    }


    static char inputChar (String prompt)
    {
 char result = (char) 0;
 try
 {
     result = input (prompt).charAt (0);
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     result = (char) 0;
 }
 return result;
    }


    static byte inputByte (String prompt)
    {
 byte result = 0;
 try
 {
     result = Byte.valueOf (input (prompt).trim ()).byteValue ();
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     result = 0;
 }
 return result;
    }


    static int inputInt (String prompt)
    {
 int result = 0;
 try
 {
     result = Integer.valueOf (input (prompt).trim ()).intValue ();
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     result = 0;
 }
 return result;
    }


    static long inputLong (String prompt)
    {
 long result = 0;
 try
 {
     result = Long.valueOf (input (prompt).trim ()).longValue ();
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     result = 0;
 }
 return result;
    }


    static double inputDouble (String prompt)
    {
 double result = 0;
 try
 {
     result = Double.valueOf (input (prompt).trim ()).doubleValue ();
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     result = 0;
 }
 return result;
    }


    static boolean inputBoolean (String prompt)
    {
 boolean result = false;
 try
 {
     result = Boolean.valueOf (input (prompt).trim ()).booleanValue ();
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     result = false;
 }
 return result;
    }
}
```

Sorry for the lengthy question. Im new to Java.

Comment: `while(end != 'y')` runs the body if `end != 'y'`. What value does `end` have at this point?

Comment: end would have any value other than 'y' (i think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computer is doing exactly what you told it to. When `GuessGame`'s constructor runs:

1. Declare `end` as a `char` local variable and initialise it to contain `'y'`:

   ```
   char end = 'y';
   ```
2. Run the loop body while `end` does not contain `'y'`:

   ```
   while (end!='y')
   ```

   (since `end` *does* contain `'y'` it does *not* run the loop body; it skips to the code after the loop).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you will never enter the initial loop

```
char end = 'y';
while (end!='y')
```

You instantiate `end` to `y`, then enter only if `end` is not `y` which will always be false, hence never enter the loop.

Simply change the default value of `end`

```
char end = 'n';
```

Also, you don't have to cast the value 0 in your IBIO class

```
result = (char) 0;
```

You can simply do `result = 0` and it will take the ASCII value.

I would also declare `num` and `guess` outside of the loop to avoid re-declaring them each time, as you did for `end`.

Finally, instead of declaring 7 `output` method with different paremeter type which simply do a `System.out.println` of the received parameter I would directly call `System.out.println(value)`.

I would apply the same logic for all other methods that only call one method with the received parameter.

Comment: @KunalRishi You're welcome. Please mark the favorite of 3 answers as accepted, so other knows it solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines clearly contradict each other, the while loop will never execute. Initialize end to be a different value.

char end = 'y';

while (end!='y')

Comment: Thank you, i didn't notice this previously! I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

You initialize the variable char end with value 'y'.

```
char end = 'y';
```

Then the condition for your loop is

```
while (end!='y')
```

This condition is never fulfilled, that's why it's out of the loop. Change the initial value of the variable end.